# tiny URL api Automati in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, twitter, bit.ly

i am working in application of twitter in flex 3 and action script 3 , this in the text area when the user write my application automatically change http address  to a short address but   i don't know  find the address within the text you can help me please..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use http webservices try to use one provided by bit.ly to shorten url

http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/shorten

http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=2.0.1&longUrl=' + textarea.text}" result="doSomething(event)"/>

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this api, so research before use:  http://userflex.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/tinyurl-flex-library/

It looks like a set of utility functions a simple as: TinyURL.create(url,callbackFunction);

Best of luck,
Jeremy